# node and npm and brew command not found with no reason?

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, node-modules

Suddenly node and npm and brew didn't work

I tried to install brew and node again with different versions but still not working

When I open terminal and write node or npm etc -v  ,
I got command not found

[/usr/local/bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfftu.png)

I dont know if I should write the path but I did it anyway

[PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KEQc.png)

Comment: Note : i have macbook pro bigSure

Answer (score 0):

Wrong PATH. Replace the last 4 lines in your zshrc with

```sh
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

PS: you'd better paste your zshrc as text when you ask a question.

Comment: @Aziz Not enough info. Can you open a shell and get the output of `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`? Please prepend the output into the original post.

Comment: @Aziz I got it. You're not putting zsh config into a wrong place. Modify `PATH` in `~/.zshrc` instead.

Comment: thank you for replying , I did everything you said , then i started to play around until i messed up a lot of things , so I decided to format my mac to start over. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh"
May be this command can help in such cases.